# PHPCrawl fails to create SSL socket

Tags: php, sockets, ssl, https, web-crawler

I'm trying to use PHPCrawl (http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpcrawl/) to trawl a website delivered over HTTPS.

I can see that there is support for SSL in the PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest class (openSocket method):

```
// If ssl -> perform Server name indication
  if ($this->url_parts["protocol"] == "https://")
  {
    $context = stream_context_create(array('ssl' => array('SNI_server_name' => $this->url_parts["host"])));
    $this->socket = @stream_socket_client($protocol_prefix.$ip_address.":".$this->url_parts["port"], $error_code, $error_str,
                                          $this->socketConnectTimeout, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $context);
  }
```

The problem lies in the call to stream_socket_client - although it returns a zero error_code, and no error_str, this->socket is still false.

The documentation for the method states the following:

> If the value returned in errno is 0 and the function returned FALSE, it is an indication that the error occurred before the connect() call.

(See http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)

So I've tried to use an example provided in the comments section to modify the stream context using 'stream_context_set_option' to set verify_host and verify_peer to false - neither of which seems to have any effect.

I'm not very proficient in PHP or the intricacies of web - does anyone know either:

- What condition (specifically) can cause this call to fail?
  OR
- A workaround for the issue?

I should note - I am using Facebook (HTTPS) as the test server.

Answer (score 2):

I've found the issue -

- PHP versions 5.6.x turn peer verification on by default, and apparently the necesarry cert isn't found sometimes ([see this bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/phpcrawl/bugs/86/))
- The workaround is to drop back to a PHP version prior to 5.6

Comment: no need to drop back a PHP version. See [this link](https://sourceforge.net/p/phpcrawl/bugs/86/) for a few solutions. Alternatively simply overwrite the PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest.class.php with the code found here - https://github.com/merzilla/phpcrawl/blob/fix-php56-ssl-problem/libs/PHPCrawlerHTTPRequest.class.php#L537

Comment: @MohamedOmar great! thanks for letting me know. nice to hear good feedback about stuff i wrote nearly 2 years ago. :-D Maybe i should post this comment as a proper answer if it's helpful..

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but I had the same problem using the PHPCrawler. What worked for me, is what an user wrote on sourceforge (Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/phpcrawl/bugs/86/#5993).

What you have to do, is to rewrite the stream_context_create call on line 547 in PHPCrawlerHTTPReqeust.class.php into the following:

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'SNI_server_name' => $this->url_parts["host"],
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    )
));
```

Hope this helps someone in the future.