# https host unreachable when crawling with PHPCrawler

Tags: php, https, web-crawler, phpcrawl

When trying to crawl a website with https protocol PHPCrawler returns an error, saying

```
Error connecting to https://www.something.com: Host unreachable ().
```

However it does crawl sites with `http://` protocol. 
My Question is why is this happening, and Is there any way PHPCrawler can crawl sites with https protocol. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm having the same problem.

Comment: It's probably the following problem, making this a duplicate.  I'm going to verify.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29403231/phpcrawl-fails-to-create-ssl-socket

Answer (score 0):

Simply just deactivate your wordfence plugin and then try to crawling again.I'd the same issue and fixed it by doing this.After successfully crawling activate your wordfence plugin again.